# How can I solve this Possible three letter words

Tags: php

I want to solve this problem of Possible three letter words

```
Here is following words. (17 characters)
19920620forestJSR
How many possible ways to make 3 length word with given characters?
Ex: 192, 162, Rer, ….
Rule:
Number 0 is different alpha o. (0 != o)
case-sensitive is available. (R != r)
same character repeat not available. (rr1 : wrong)
Hint:
17 16 15 : wrong
```

How can I solve this

I am trying with this code

```
function permute($str,$i,$n) {
   if ($i == $n)
       print "$str\n";
   else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
          swap($str,$i,$j);
          permute($str, $i+1, $n);
          swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}


function swap(&$str,$i,$j) {
    $temp = $str[$i];
    $str[$i] = $str[$j];
    $str[$j] = $temp;
}   

$str='19920620forestJSR';
permute($str,0,strlen($str));
```

But in output have some error with numeric characters

Output look like (when str=19920620forestJSR)

```
n���Z��뢿�Yh��fzj+�ȳz��ߍ�ｼo+^��aj�-y�k��m��e�ƭ{�6�ټ�zȧo�h���j���Z�ǫ���������z�a���X�y�����
```

Output look like (when str=forestJSR)

```
foresSJtR
foresSJRt
foresStJR
foresStRJ
foresSRtJ
foresSRJt
foresRJSt
foresRJtS
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules says you need combinations of *3* characters, *whithout* repeating letters. Your code is generating all combinations for 17 letters. So, the script is looping for millions of possibilities (355,687,428,096,000).

The number of permutations of n distinct objects, taken r at a time is

```
nPr = n! / (n - r)!
```

So, for "19920620forestJSR" (14 different letters only), using 3 at a time:

```
14P3 = 14! / (14 - 3)! = 14! / 11! = (14)(13)(12) = 2184
```